# Langchain Chatbot with Memory + Vector Database

Tags: nlp, chatbot, language-model, langchain

In Langchain, what is the suggested way to build a chatbot with memory and retrieval from a vector embedding database at the same time?

The examples in the [docs](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/memory/how_to_guides.html) add memory modules to chains that do not have a vector database. Related [issue](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/issues/2185).

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this, but this Weaviate blog post might be helpful https://weaviate.io/blog/combining-langchain-and-weaviate